# Implementing PartialEq for a struct with From types

Tags: struct, rust, traits

I am trying to implement `PartialEq` between a struct I created and other types for which my struct implements the `From` trait. The real code is more complex and implements `From` for other types, but this is a stripped down version of the core problem.

I want to be able to do:

```
let s = Data::from(5);
assert_eq!(5, s);
```

This is the base code:

```
struct Data {
    data: i64,
}

impl From<i64> for Data {
    fn from(v: i64) -> Data {
        Data { data: v }
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a i64> for Data {
    fn from(v: &'a i64) -> Data {
        Data { data: v.clone() }
    }
}
```

This was my first try:

```
impl<T> PartialEq<T> for Data
    where T: Into<Data>
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &T) -> bool {
        let o = Data::from(other);
        self.data == o.data
    }
}
```

but I get an error:

```
error: the trait bound `Data: std::convert::From<&T>` is not satisfied [--explain E0277]
  --> <anon>:21:17
   |>
21 |>         let o = Data::from(other);
   |>                 ^^^^^^^^^^
help: consider adding a `where Data: std::convert::From<&T>` bound
note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

So I changed the trait bound to what the compiler suggested and added all the requested lifetimes to fix the `missing lifetime specifier` error:

```
impl<'a, T> PartialEq<T> for Data
    where T: 'a, Data: From<&'a T>
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &'a T) -> bool {
        let o = Data::from(other);
        self.data == o.data
    }
}
```

From which I get

```
error: method not compatible with trait [--explain E0308]
  --> <anon>:31:5
   |>
31 |>     fn eq(&self, other: &'a T) -> bool {
   |>     ^ lifetime mismatch
note: expected type `fn(&Data, &T) -> bool`
note:    found type `fn(&Data, &'a T) -> bool`
note: the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the block at 31:39...
  --> <anon>:31:40
   |>
31 |>     fn eq(&self, other: &'a T) -> bool {
   |>                                        ^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 31:39
  --> <anon>:31:40
   |>
31 |>     fn eq(&self, other: &'a T) -> bool {
   |>                                        ^
help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn eq(&self, other: &'a T) -> bool
  --> <anon>:31:5
   |>
31 |>     fn eq(&self, other: &'a T) -> bool {
   |>     ^
```

And now I'm lost, as it suggests to do exactly what I did and it refused... :/

[**Code on the playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=157f07204d2b780e4deb5ca653605741&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need one tiny modification to make that `PartialEq` work: require `Data: From<&'a T>` since you're using `Data::from(other)` and not `other.into()`:

```
impl<T> PartialEq<T> for Data
    where for<'a> Data: From<&'a T>
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &T) -> bool {
        let o = Data::from(other);
        self.data == o.data
    }
}
```

You also need two tiny modifications to make the `assert_eq!` work:

1. Since you're implementing PartialEq for Data, the RHS is `T` and the LHS is `Data`, so you can only compare using `Data::from(5) == 5` and not `5 == Data::from(5)`.
2. You need to implement `Debug` if you want to use `assert_eq!`.

Final working code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Data {
    data: i64,
}

impl From<i64> for Data {
    fn from(v: i64) -> Data {
        Data { data: v }
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a i64> for Data {
    fn from(v: &'a i64) -> Data {
        Data { data: v.clone() }
    }
}

impl<T> PartialEq<T> for Data
    where for<'a> Data: From<&'a T>
{
    fn eq(&self, other: &T) -> bool {
        let o = Data::from(other);
        self.data == o.data
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = Data::from(5);
    assert_eq!(s, 5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the `for` in the `where` clause.

Comment: @Shu: The `for` is there to introduce the lifetime name, semantically it means that the following relationships should be valid whatever the value of `'a`.

Answer (score 9):

The compiler is right: adding `where Data: From<&T>` *is* the right thing to do. But as you already noticed, a lifetime specifier is required in this case. But **how** do we declare it?

What we want to say to the compiler:

> `Data` should implement `From<&'a T>` for **any** lifetime `'a`

We *can't* declare the lifetime on the `impl` block, because this expresses something different. We instead need to use [“higher-ranked lifetime bounds”](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html), as shown here:

```
    where Data: for<'a> From<&'a T>
//              ^^^^^^^
```

This fixes your main problem.

---

There are two minor, unrelated, additional problems:

- you need to swap the arguments in `assert_eq!()`, because of the way `PartialEq` is used: `assert_eq!(s, 5)`
- you need to `#[derive(Debug)]` for your `Data` type

You can find a **working version** [here on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f0c483b2ca7321ade4d9dc112a3d33bb&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: Thanks to you too. I accepted Dogbert's answer because it was the fastest, but the link to the nomicon is much appreciated.